# How to print a vector in reverse order?

Tags: c, printing

I have a vector (`v`) whose elements are ordered from lowest to highest. In order to print the items in reverse order (from highest to lowest), I have decided to write this code:

```
void highest_lowest(int v[], int size) {
    int i;

    for (i = size; i >= 1; i--) {
        printf("v[%d] = %d\n", i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

but it prints this:

```
v[4] = 2003516626
v[3] = 6422476
v[2] = -2
v[1] = 6422108
```

Does anyone know where the error is??

Comment: `where the error is??` Array indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

The index should vary from `size-1` to `0` inclusive. An idiomatic way to write this loop is:

```
void highest_lowest(int v[], int size) {
    for (int i = size; i-- > 0;) {
        printf("v[%d] = %d\n", i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

Post-decrementing `i` in the test has 2 advantages:

- `i` is initialized to the array size, not `size-1`.
- `i` could have an unsigned type such as `size_t`, which would make the test `i >= 0` inoperant.

Answer (score 1):

In arrays/vectors the index goes from `0` to `(size-1)` or `array_length -1`.

In your solution/code the first iteration in the for loop, have began from `size` which is out of vector bounds!

`v[size]` is out of the vector boundaries!

We can get the last element in the vector with the expression: `v[size-1]`

another issue, you didn't print the first item because you have stopped at `i = 1`

```
void highest_lowest(int v[], int size){
  
  for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i){
    printf("v[%d] = %d\n", i, v[i]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use reverse_iterators.

```
for (auto it=v.rbegin(); it!=v.rend(); it++)
{
   std::cout << *it << std.endl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C array's indexes start at 0, array variable contains address of the first element,

```
*array-----+
           |
           V
          +-+-+-+-+
          |1|2|3|4|
          +-+-+-+-+
```

that means if you add 1 to that address (array[1]) you get 2nd element, not the first

```
array[1]-----+
             |
             V
          +-+-+-+-+
          |1|2|3|4|
          +-+-+-+-+
```

That means you start counting from *"size - 1"* to *"0"*, by counting from "size" you get outside of array's boundaries